# Finite sum calculation.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot k!$$

but with no success. Does anyone have suggestion/hints?

Comment: You should try numerical experiments (small $n$, say 3, 4, 5), conjecturing a closed form, and proving the result (say, via induction).

Comment: @Nitin That would work with something like $\sum k, \sum k^2$ but I don't think there's an easy expression for the sum the OP asked about

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect that there is a closed form for this sum?

Comment: prove by induction that $$\sum_{k=1}^nkk!= \left( 1+n \right) !-1$$

Comment: @Ant there is an easy expression... In fact, it's harder with $\sum k$ and $\sum k^2$ because guessing the quadratic/cubic is impossible/hard without a fitting procedure.

Comment: @Nitin What? what you said is just wrong :) Finding the expression for $\sum k^i$ is easy, because you know that it's a polynomial of of a certain degree, so you can compute the coefficients (by hand!) and then prove with induction. Even if you don't know that the result will be a polynomial in $n$, polynomials are the easiest thing to "guess" if you're trying to fit a series. My point is that in general finite sums (except polynomials / geometric series) don't have closed form expression (or if they do, they are very complicated and involving "special functions").

Comment: @Nitin (continued) So that you don't expect to be able to solve a complicated-looking summation by "guessing" the general form and then using induction. Take for example the closed form solution for $\sum k!$: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k! = \frac{-e+Ei(1) +\pi i + E_{n+2} (-1) \Gamma(n+2)}{e}$$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html). You're not going to guess that! In this case we lucked out because it is an alternating series, but that's not what you would expect. So that was the point of my original comment :)

Comment: @Ant we're on the same page here. My advice for this example was very specific because I knew the answer ($(n+1)! - 1$) and that it could be guessed in easily. My point about the polynomials is that it is impossible to find the closed form by just staring at the numbers (hence what I said about a fitting procedure, in agreement with what you said). And yes of course in general it is hard to find $\sum_n f(n)$. Again, my advice was very specific to this example.

Comment: @Nitin Ah, I see; I have misunderstood then. Good to be on the same page :)

Answer (score 7):

One can write

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k! = \sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)! - \sum_{k=1}^n k!$$

This is a telescopic sum (i.e. each term cancels the next one, so only the first one and the last one remain) which means that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot k!  = (n+1)! - 1$$